Install VMware Horizon Client via GPO
I need to install VMware Horizon Client silently on several computers, I wanted to do it through a GPO but I can't find the way.
I guess the way to do it would be a PowerShell script that runs via GPO at startup or logon.
First I just tried with a .bat, and I don't know how to do a PowerShell script that solves that problem.
I tried looking for a GPO to install programs, but only Windows installation files (.msi) can be executed.
I tried to create a script to install the program but it didn't work.
Here's the script in the .bat file:

@echo off
"C:\\Users\\jcastanyer\\Downloads\\VMware-Horizon-Client-2312.1-8.12.1-23531249.exe" /s
exit


You're on the right track with using GPO for installation as a PowerShell startup script. Copy the executable install file to a UNC path, ensuring Domain Computers or Authenticated Users have read NTFS access and share permissions.
Utilize Start-Process to initiate the installation and include the /s parameter during execution to perform a silent installation with the PowerShell script logic.
The GPO startup script can be on a UNC path or embedded within the GPO. Ensure Domain Computers or Authenticated Users have Read and Execute permissions if using a UNC path.

PowerShell
$Pkg = "\\serverxyz\packages\install\VMware-Horizon-Client-2312.1-8.12.1-23531249.exe";
Start-Process -FilePath $Pkg -ArgumentList '/s' -Wait;
Exit;


You will have to play with using -wait parameter or not. Test it and see how it works both ways after you have it all setup in GPO, run repadmin /AdeP /Syncall on your DC(s), then gpupdate on the client, then reboot the client and watch the screen. Do it both with and without the -Wait parameter as you test and watch the screen both ways to see the difference in your environment. Might see "please wait" longer with -wait and without it, it may allow users to login before it is fully installed so it may appear broken until the install finishes, test it out though to see for yourself.

I meant repadmin /syncall /AdeP.... I typed the parameters in the previous comment in the wrong order, that way will error out. In any event, just test if this solution will suffice but works well for me on hundreds of computers in my experience.
